# VB.Net button open multiple user and auto login in different window of IE

Tags: vb.net

I have a website stored 100 users ....now i want to create a VB form with 100 buttons ....while i click button1, it will open IE then log in users1 automatic and when i click button2 , it will open IE then log in as user2 automatic. user3 until user100 the same ....click from button on vb form.
Note : i am already done to set open IE and log in as different users in each windows but now i am finding how to set auto log in with different users in the same website when i click each button in form.

i have something more about form....i will use ( 100 button click = 100 users = 100 IE window ....)
it depend on user click on button that he need to log in......because we don't know that what button/users/time will he want to click .....

I really need your help urgently...
Thank in advanced.

here is some code of Button_Click

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Using p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://test.com"
        p.Start()
    End Using
```

Comment: What have you done so far code wise?

Comment: excuse me .....what you mean ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you supply some code? Asking for help (and asking for an urgent response) before actually trying is not the way to go.

Comment: @WozzeC added code to article already

Comment: Missed that. I know of one way to fix this I think. Btw is the login on the site made from POST? i.e. is the username and password sent using a form and a submit button?

Comment: @WozzeC , i am so sorry for late reply.....i am not sure about your advised ....please give me full detail , thanks

Comment: Do you actually want to load 100 separate browser windows at one? Or just one at a time? Im sure this is very simple, but i dont quite understand what you want to do

Comment: @user574632 i will use ( 100 button click = 100 users = 100 IE window ....) it depend on user click on button that he need to log in......because we don't know that what button/users/time will he want to click .....
please help
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can come up with on how to solve this.

My guess is that your login is using POST variables, it's pretty much standard.

To make this work you would have to allow the username and password to be supplied with GET. That is, sending them in the url like this:

http://test.com/login.php/asp?username=username&password=password

Since you haven't specified whether you use PHP or ASP.NET I will add info on how to get the value for both:
ASP.NET
Request.Querystring("username")
PHP
$_GET["username"];

Comment: , sorry for late reply....
but this seem you telling me to write code in my website,
right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can't start a process with post data which means the info must be in the link. You must also target the link in <form action="thislink">. Then as mentioned you need to check for both POST (from the login on the webpage) and GET(from your application)

Comment: If you are not able to change your code then you need to leave the idea of using process and create a function that can perform a web requst containing post and display the result in a WebBrowserControl as the other answer implies.

Comment: Hmmmm sorry i don't understand you mean :(

Comment: I can't help you more than this without you supplying the loginpage on the website. But to be honest, if you don't get this you should consider reading up your skills in web development.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on comment

You are correct it is not possible to isolate separate webbrowser controls.
I would suggest you look into either WaTin to control separate IE instances, or Awsomium .NET, which i believe allows separate sessions in 1.7, though i haven't tested it.

Also be aware that since IE8 session cookies are shared across instanced by default, so you would need to run them with the -nomerge flag. WaTin supports this.

Based on the fact that you have not mentioned this in your question, i am presuming you are using IE7. If that is the case, and this application is not intended to be used on other machines, it should be possible to create a separate application with an embeded webbrowser control, then launch multiple insatances of that application from the main one, so you can add your own communication mechanism, but WaTin is probably a far better idea

OLD ANSWER:

It is very hard to work out what you want to do, but im guessing you want to create a winforms app, that lets you to choose a user account, and then open a browser and login to a website with that account.

Based on that assumption, my suggestion would be to have one button, and some way of selecting the account, say a comboBox, and a webbrowser control:

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/888/66649645.jpg

Rather than 1 button per user account and trying to manipulate an external browser.
If this is indeed what you want to do, comment and i will edit my answer as required, and provide starting code if you need, but i cant do that without really undertanding what you need to do.

Comment: sorry for late reply.....first thanks so much,
i can't use webbrowser control....because it can't make me can log in 100 users and 100 window.....in the same time, i already to test it .....if i login second user .....second user will overwrite fist user.....but internet explorer(IE) can login multiple users on each window ......so now i just need setting code when i click button1 it will automatic log in as user1  then when i click another button...it will log in as another account .....note: all users stored in the same website !

Comment: Create a form containing the webcontrol and then create a new form for every button. That should work. And as a reply to what he's trying to do. I think of it as if he has a function that counts the amount of currently logged in users. Only way to test it is to log in a lot of users simultaniously.

Comment: updated my answer. @WozzeC unfortunatly that would not work, sessions are on a per process basis. I am guessing this is some kind of testing app. If it is indeed just to simulate logged in users, it would be 100x easier to just use webrequests

Comment: @user574632
Sorry i really don't know what to do with your answer....please help full answer with source code .....thanks and please

Comment: @WozzeC Sorry i really don't know what to do with your answer....please help full answer with source code .....thanks and please

Comment: @User5746
Thanks you so much ! with Webtin really good solution.....but let's me ask you one more why my vb form always to be stuck when i click button to open IE ?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to run your waTin code in a background thread to avoid blocking the ui thread *which causes your form to be 'stuck'. I will edit my answer this evening with examples when i get a chance

Comment: hmmmmmm now waTin can't help me !


i need source code that open multiple webbrowser in visual basic 2010 Each of them has their own session. So I can open many website account from 1 form that have multiple browser....

Please help me ...i think awesomium or webbrowser control can help me but i don't know how to write code 
Thanks